# Do we have any footage of the Millennium Falcon landing?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

Do we have any footage of the Millennium Falcon landing? Even better with what happens inside controls-wise? I'm trying to make a fan fiction more accurate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We see the [Falcon landing at Bespin](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x9lags_millenium-falcon-landing-at-bespin_shortfilms) in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

[image: The Millennium Falcon, landing pads lowered, drifts slowly onto a landing platform from the right, against the orangish sky of Bespin. A cloud car flies by, then forward thrusters fire slowing it's horizontal motion. Downward thrusters fire as it lowers onto the pad.]

Unfortunately there's no internal cockpit footage.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of what controls they would be using, other than those little thrusters which fire at the last second to decrease velocity?

Comment: @ThomasShera - There's no major descriptions in the novels. If I had to guess (based on my knowledge of Star Wars), I'd imagine that when making their final approach, they're powering down the main engines, turning off the navicomp, operating the control yoke to keep the ship level, switching to repulsorlift engines to slow them down and then turning on automated control thrusters to allow the ship's dedicated astro-droid brain to guide the final landing sequence.

Comment: thx, sounds like a pretty good guess to me. Marked as answer.

Comment: @ThomasShera Try reseaching what happens with Harrier jet landings [\[1\]](https://youtu.be/QG_bgVvXtsk?t=150) [\[2\]](https://youtu.be/y_vu4NwoZrs?t=255). They are VTOL-capable.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist - I watched that whole video and I was unable to see any evidence of him turning his repulsorlift engines on.

Comment: @Richard For lack of movies showing us what happens in a cockpit on vertical landing I suggested the Harrier for (fanfic) inspiration purposes. Mind you, if you don't see repulsorlift engines being turned on, that's perhaps because like in the Harrier this is "automatic": The engines swivel from back-facing to down-facing gradually, in response to commands from the yoke. If we can do it, a technologically far more advanced ship in a galaxy far, far away should be able to do that with ease.

Comment: I love that the ship stops moving, pauses, then fires the reverse & landing thrusters which cause the ship to fall a moment later :)